# Why is not showing ValidationError?

Tags: django, validationerror

I just started learning Django and have a problem with ValidationError which is not displaying in my browser.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm
from .models import Product

def product_create_view(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ProductForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "products/product_create.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
def class_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')      
    if "abc" in title:          
       return title
    else:           
        raise forms.ValidationError("This is not a valid title")
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: django version- 2.0.7

Comment: Are you sure `class_title` is ever called?

Comment: I think you mean `clean_title`, not `class_title`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oops sorry lol, Thanks a lot!